# loading data into singly linked list from file in c

Tags: c, file, linked-list

I would like to load the data back into the linked list after i terminate the program and run it the second time. But the previous list of data doesn't store back into the linked list the second time i run

insert with singly linked list:

```
    tick *addinfo(tick *previous,char* serial,char* ticketno,char* name,char* id)
  {

     tick *info = malloc(sizeof(tick));
    info->nextPtr = NULL;
    info->visitor.SrNo =strdup(serial);
    info->visitor.ticketNo = strdup(ticketno);
    info->visitor.Name = strdup(name);
    info->visitor.ID= strdup(id);

    if (previous != NULL)
    {
        previous->nextPtr = info;
    }

    printf("visitor info has been added: %s %s %s %s",info->visitor.SrNo,info->visitor.ticketNo,info->visitor.Name,info->visitor.ID);
    ptroutfile=fopen("output.txt","a");
    fprintf(ptroutfile,"visitor info has been added: %s %s %s %s\n\n",info->visitor.SrNo,info->visitor.ticketNo,info->visitor.Name,info->visitor.ID);
    fclose(ptroutfile);

    return info;
}
```

readfile function:

```
    void readfile(tick* startPtr)
    {
       FILE* cfptr=NULL;
       char srno[20],ticketNo[20],name[30],id[20];
       cfptr=fopen("ticket.txt","r");

       while(fscanf(cfptr,"%s %s %s %s",srno,ticketNo,name,id) == 4)
       {
          tick *info = malloc(sizeof(tick));
          info->nextPtr = NULL;
          info->visitor.SrNo =strdup(srno);
          info->visitor.ticketNo = strdup(ticketNo);
          info->visitor.Name = strdup(name);
          info->visitor.ID= strdup(id);

          if (startPtr != NULL)
          {
              startPtr->nextPtr = info;
          }

     }

     fclose(cfptr);
}
```

Calling the function in main:

```
int main ()
{

   tick *visitorinfo = NULL;
   tick *new = NULL;

    readfile(visitorinfo);

}
```

Comment: As of now your question is not clear. Please add more details

Comment: did you check that the file contains what you expect